# Recreate the upload folder from a website without having access to the backend/cpanel/filezilla directly from the website

Tags: images, uploads

Here's my scenario:

I'm working on a website, I have access to the dashboard on WordPress BUT:

1. I can't install plugins.
2. I don't have access to all the folders except for wp-content.
3. I don't have access to the Cpanel/filezilla

I'm able to work on the website and copy the database, but I don't have access to the default image folder, UPLOAD but in order to recreate the structure of the website, I should paste and copy ALL the pages, then extract the images, then create other folder and, at the end of the day, place the images files there and then I could be ok.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do it differently..

Like a chrome extension, some WordPress native function, so anything else.. from outside that website because I'm recreating the website locally.

Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what your user privileges are - are you an admin, editor, author, etc? An admin-level should be able to install plugins via Plugins, Add New.

Most new-to-WP people don't realize that access to the folder structure (via cPanel or FTP) is not needed to admin the site. Any installation of themes/plugins is done via admin access, at the admin-rolelevel. Any adding of images to the uploads folder is done via the admin panel Media entry, or when adding/editing a post/page (assuming you have privs/ro;e to do that).

If your user is an admin-level role, then you should be able to add plugins (via Plugins, Add New), or add media (via Media page, or when adding/editing a page/post). If you aren't an admin-level role (which is different than logging into the admin panel), then your capabilities are limited.

To understand roles and privileges, see https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/ .